# Why does the NS records keep randomly changing?

Tags: domain-name-system

```
dig NS soundshare.co.uk


;; ANSWER SECTION:
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-1179.awsdns-19.org.
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-1909.awsdns-46.co.uk.
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-311.awsdns-38.com.
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-972.awsdns-57.net.
```

a few seconds later:

```
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-1289.awsdns-33.org.
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-1581.awsdns-05.co.uk.
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-41.awsdns-05.com.
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-806.awsdns-36.net.
```

Why might this be occuring?

These are all values that I've previously set. Should I get in contact with the domain provider?

Comment: If you specifiy `dig @server` to make sure you query every time the same name server (i.e. `dig @1.1.1.1 soundshare.co.uk -t NS`), do the records still vary?

Comment: problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Anycast network, I'd say.

Also, as pointed out by Fabian, your resolver might use an anycast network, too (Google, Quad9, CloudFlare) and thus you get different results based on which actual resolver asks the question.

Both are not things, your usual mon-and-pop ISP would do, but here we are in 2018 and a lot of stuff is more complicated behind the scenes than it may look at first glance...

Comment: So would these results eventually converge to the latest values? It's around 12 hours since I've changed them.

Comment: Why do you care? As long as it works.

Comment: I just checked and the first answer is what is in whois currently. The TTL is quite long, so the resolvers you use might have different values cached.

intodns.com and mxtoolbox.com show no irregularities, apart from the odd choice of the serial number "1".

Comment: Because I actually set those NS records, and they point to two different VPCs in AWS. The service that I'm using seems to work intermittently, which I'm guessing is due to the incorrect NS values being returned occasionally.